# Why @inject constructor generate Factory file

Tags: dagger-2

I used @Inject -annotated constructor to create instances.

@Inject constructor

```
class Drink @Inject constructor(){
    fun show(){
        Log.d("test", "Cola")
    }
}
```

component

```
@Component
interface DrinkShop{
    fun buyInShop(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Inject field

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var drink: Drink
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        DaggerDrinkShop.create().buyInShop(this)
        drink.show()
    }
}
```

I took a look at generated code. I found that Factory file is not used by other files.

Why dagger2 generate Factory file that not be used?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you could give a minimal code sample and description to reproduce your issue.